# Using Selenium commands in Katalon

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, katalon

How can I use Selenium commands in Katalon Studio? There is a commands reference on Katalon site, but I can't seem to call those from my scripts written in the Katalon script writing tool.

https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Selenese+%28Selenium+IDE%29+Commands+Reference

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import selenium class in the katalon script window

for example:
to use "Webdriver"

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
```

like this we have call the required selenium classname

Answer (score 1):

How to import Selenium IDE test cases into Katalon Studio

In the Katalon [Selenium IDE](https://a9t9.com/blog/selenium-ide-2018/), select the test case that you want to export. Select File > Save test case as. We need to save the test case as HTML format to import into Katalon Automation Recorder. Provide a name with “.html” and click Save.

Next, to import into Katalon Automation Recorder, start Katalon Automation Recorder extension (Chrome) or addon (Firefox), click 3 vertical dots at the end of Test case explorer, select Open Test Suite from the drop-down menu...

From: https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/4220/how-to-import-selenium-ide-test-cases-into-katalon-studio